# Linux: How to get notified of newly created sockets?

Tags: linux

I'm looking for way to get notified immediately, in userspace, when a new socket has been created. Our existing implementation does polling read on /proc/net/tcp and /proc/net/udp, but this does not work well for very short-lived sockets (e.g. send datagram and close).

Comment: What are you really trying to do. I suspect you would be buried in noise if you actually got notifications for *every* new socket. Linux uses sockets *a lot*...

Comment: Do you mean socket object creation (`struct socket`) for a particular family and type? Or do you mean connection establishment?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

- Auditing the `socket` or `socketcall` syscalls. If not using the `audit` daemon, this requires writing some netlink code. If you want to coexist with other userspace trying to access the audit system, you'll need the 3.15 kernel for its multicast netlink sockets.
- Writing a custom linux security module that uses your favourite event mechanism to notify userspace of a new socket.
- Doing system call or library call tracing, recursively, using `strace` or `ltrace`, if you don't mind the hackiness, raciness, and overhead.
- Replacing the socket system calls with a shim layer. Requires writing your own kernel module.
- Ftracing with the `function` tracer, and limiting the functions to trace to either the socket syscall, or the type-specific initialization functions it delegates to.
- Kprobing the previously mentioned kernel functions of interest, and using your favourite mechanism of notifying userspace.